# How To Change Status From Canceled to Processing In Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I need to **Change order status from canceled to processing**, how can I do it from my backend. Is it possible or reorder my order?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using amasty's [Mass Product Actions | v1.7.1](https://amasty.com/mass-product-actions.html) 
For this purpose.

[image]

**OR**

Refer to this [link](https://amirshakya.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/how-to-change-order-status-in-magento/) for an alternate solution

locate `config.xml` under `Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\etc\`

Find this block of code:

```
<states>
                    <new translate="label">
                        <label>New</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <pending/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front/>
                    </new>
                    <pending_payment translate="label">
                        <label>Pending Payment</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <pending_paypal/>
                        </statuses>
                    </pending_payment>
                    <processing translate="label">
                        <label>Processing</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <processing/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front/>
                    </processing>
                    <complete translate="label">
                        <label>Complete</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <complete/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front/>
                    </complete>
                    <closed translate="label">
                        <label>Closed</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <closed/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front/>
                    </closed>
                    <canceled translate="label">
                        <label>Canceled</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <canceled/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front/>
                    </canceled>
                    <holded translate="label">
                        <label>On Hold</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <holded/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front/>
                    </holded>
                </states>
Change it to this:
<states>
  <new translate="label">
    <label>New</label>
    <statuses>
      <pending/>
      <processing/>
      <holded/>
      <complete/>
      <closed/>
      <canceled/>
    </statuses>
  </new>
  <pending translate="label">
    <label>Pending</label>
    <statuses>
      <pending/>
      <processing/>
      <holded/>
      <complete/>
      <closed/>
      <canceled/>
    </statuses>
  </pending>
  <processing translate="label">
    <label>Processing</label>
    <statuses>
      <pending/>
      <processing/>
      <holded/>
      <complete/>
      <closed/>
      <canceled/>
    </statuses>
  </processing>
  <complete translate="label">
    <label>Complete</label>
    <statuses>
      <complete/>
      <pending/>
      <processing/>
      <holded/>
      <closed/>
      <canceled/>
    </statuses>
  </complete>
  <closed translate="label">
    <label>Closed</label>
    <statuses>
      <pending/>
      <processing/>
      <holded/>
      <complete/>
      <closed/>
      <canceled/>
    </statuses>
  </closed>
  <canceled translate="label">
    <label>Canceled</label>
    <statuses>
      <pending/>
      <processing/>
      <holded/>
      <complete/>
      <closed/>
      <canceled/>
    </statuses>
  </canceled>
  <holded translate="label">
    <label>On Hold</label>
      <statuses>
      <pending/>
      <processing/>
      <holded/>
      <complete/>
      <closed/>
      <canceled/>
    </statuses>
  </holded>
</states>
```

Save the file.

Refresh your cache in Magento.

That should now allow you to manually change order status in Magento Commerce.

Comment: there are no changes, for ur 2nd option